# Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GoogleAdMobInterstitial

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, mopub

I am adding Google Play Servcies (admob) ads through mopub using the link

https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-with-Google-Play-Services

I followed all the steps but when I run the code it shows me error
Couldn't locate or instantiate custom event: com.mopub.mobileads.GoogleAdMobBanner

After reading the topic http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/785346-issues-with-admob-proguard
I added the below lines in proguard-project.txt file of my project and sdk project proguard.cfg file but issue is still not solve. Please help.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil {*;}

# AdMob Support
-keep class com.google.ads.**


-keepclassmembers class com.mopub.mobileads.* { public *; }

-keep public class com.mopub.mobileads.*
```

Answer (score 1):

You were looking at the outdated instructions. Please follow this guide:
https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/google-play-services